Reasonable implementation of a MILP scheduling problem
I have the following (fairly classical) "big-M" formulation of a scheduling problem. I am not able to solve it in reasonable amount of time for instances with more than 20 jobs (I am using the HiGHS solver). Surely the problem is NP-hard, but if the deadlines are not tight, then the solution should be trivial to be found (just a random permutation would work).
Problem: there is just one machine on which we have to schedule $n$ jobs. Each job $j$ has a deadline $d_j$, and we want to minimize the sum of the tardinesses.
Parameters:
$J$: Set of jobs, indexed by $j$, where $j = 1, 2, \ldots, n$.
$d_j$: Deadline for job $j\in J$.
$t_{j}$: Processing time for job $j\in J$.
$M:=\sum_{j\in J} t_j$.
Objective function:
$\min \sum_{j\in J} \max(0, C_j + t_j - d_j)$
Decision variables:
$C_j$: Starting time of job $j\in J$.
$y_{jj'}$: Binary variable, $1$ if job $j\in J$ is processed before job $j'\in J$, $0$ otherwise.
Constraints:
Non-overlapping 1: $C_i +   t_{i} \leq C_j + M (1-y_{ij}) \quad \forall i,j\in J, i<j$.
Non-overlapping 2: $C_j + t_j \leq C_i + M y_{ij} \quad \forall i\in J, j\in J,i<j$.
Excluded middle: $y_{ij} + y_{ji} =1 \quad \forall i,j\in J, i<j$
Positivity: $C_j \geq 0 \quad \forall j\in J$
I am fairly sure I am doing something wrong, but I do not know what.

This looks correct.  How are you linearizing the objective?

I wrote it like that in AMPL. The software is taking care of it. Do you think that could be the problem?

@Gabriele, welcome to OR.SE. Is it possible to change your objective from $1 \ | |  \sum \text{tardinesses}$ to $1 \ |  | \sum \text{number of tardy jobs}$? Also, is there any other constraint?

AMPL probably performs the same linearization as in my answer.

@A.Omidi I cannot change to minimizing the number of tardy jobs. This was an idealization, because in the real scenario I have job families and setup times when the machine switches from one job family to the other. However, I guess that if I am not able to solve this simplified version, for sure I am not able to solve the more involved one either.

@Gabriele, your guess is actually correct. As you know , many of the solid scheduling problems like this fall in the NP class of decision making and there is no easy way to formulate those as a MILP. Are you willing to solve this problem by other methods?

Are you able to share the data for an instance where the solver struggles?

@A.Omidi: indeed I know I will have to go through approximate solutions, but I was surprised that already the "easy" part (without the further family constraint) on small instances takes so long.

@RobPratt: how can I share the data?

@Gabriele, the complicating part of the model is still disjunctive constraints and I am not surprised if the solving process performs being not really you expected. Also, to achieve the optimality you can still stand on the MIP based on time-indexed formulation that performs better than the formulation you mentioned. But, in the large scale instances the situation is the same. However, for this specific problem, min sum tardiness, there is a FPTAS to achieve optimal solution. Also, why not try to do it with CP?

@A.Omidi: I will certainly try the FPTAS (I guess you refer to the one in the book of Pinedo, section 3.5). But I do not know if there is an extension that can handle also job families. About CP, I am not familiar at all with it, but I shall give it a try.

You can just edit the question to include the values of $d_j$ and $t_j$.

Your formulation looks correct, but the objective is nonlinear because it includes a $\max$ function. You can linearize by introducing nonnegative variables $z_j$, imposing linear constraints $z_j \ge C_j+t_j-d_j$, and minimizing $\sum_j z_j$.
